# How can I compile two dependent js using laravel mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I am migrating my application to laravel and have migrated the code to resources js folder. I am facing an issue while using laravel-mix. I am using variables from one js file in another js file but when I compile it using laravel mix it coverts into closure and other js cript is not able to use it. Below is my code snippet:

**Before Compiling**

file1.js:

```
let var1= "var1";
let var2= "var2";
function loginModal(){}
```

file2.js:

```
if(var1 == 'something'){
loginModal()}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js(['resources/js/file1.js','resources/js/file2.js'],'public/js/file.js')
```

**after compilation**

file.js

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "/";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 15);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./resources/js/file1.js":
/*!********************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/js/file1.js ***!
  \********************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports){
let var1= "var1";
let var2= "var2";
function loginModal(){}
}),

/***/ "./resources/js/file2.js":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** ./resources/js/file2.js ***!
  \******************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports){
if(var1 == 'something'){
loginModal()}
});
```

file 1 variables are not accessible to file 2. Does anybody know how can I access variables?
Also, I have used mix.combine but it does not compile the js file and thus I am not able to access env variables in my js.

Comment: [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) them from one file and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) them in the other. As an added bonus you only need to compile the file that has the `import` then webpack will automatically add the imported files in the bundle

Answer (score 0):

try this in your resources folder

```
var var1 = require('./file1.js');
var var2 = {
    foo: 'var2'
}
console.log(object1.foo);
```